# How fast can I say your program?

Tags: code-challenge, unicode

I recently decided to download some dictation software, in order to help with my writing. However, it doesn't work very well when I'm coding, since I have to change from saying words to symbols and back again. It's even worse when I'm coding in an esoteric language which is *all* symbols.

In order to make my use of the dictation program more consistent, I decided to switch it over to character mode, where I just say the name of each character instead. Problem solved! Though this does delay my novel's release date a little bit...

So, assuming that the longer the name of a character, the longer it takes to say, how long will it take me to spell out some of my programs/sentences?

### Specifications

Given a string consisting of only printable ASCII, return the sum of each character's unicode name. For example, `/` is called `SOLIDUS` with 7 characters, and `A` is `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A` with 22 characters.

But remember, I have to say your programs out loud to execute them, so their score will be based on how long it takes me to say them, i.e. as the sum of the lengths of each character's unicode name.

### Test Cases:

In format `input => output` with no trailing/leading spaces in input.

```
A      => 22
/      => 7
Once upon a time...           => 304
slurp.uninames>>.comb.sum.say => 530
JoKing => 124
!" #$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~        =>  1591
Double-check your \s on the last test case ;)   => 755
<say "<$_>~~.EVAL">~~.EVAL     => 388
,[.,]  => 58
19     => 19
```

#### Rules:

- Input to your program will only consist of printable ASCII characters, that is, the codepoints 32 (space) to 126 (tilde).

  - For convenience sake, here is the list of lengths of the characters you have to handle: `[5,16,14,11,11,12,9,10,16,17,8,9,5,12,9,7,10,9,9,11,10,10,9,11,11,10,5,9,14,11,17,13,13,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,19,15,20,17,8,12,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,18,13,19,5]`
- Here is a [reference program](https://tio.run/##dY89C8IwEIZ3f8URqGgNh6h1KXSwq6NuLlFjW2yTkA@xiP71GlOHOnhwB8dzH@@ruK7XXWdYCyQvmQaAvagEazgMY8tFYUvIpRMWdtKSdBRWgNxhNX@Z2mmFJ9kcccMKNFLbSYxX3k6zDMcPpSthL0AiA9Ei8WV5higJeRCEwmeyr@j65xRmwzacpnhjteO/g4HEPUn/gSca13iTQeWXG68sCPYIvZc3) you can use to score your program.

  - Peter Taylor has pointed out that the reference program normalises some [unicode characters](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLBwsTCTC85o0gvvyjl/38A). It should still work for most solutions, but feel free to correct it if you need
- Since you're saying what the characters actually look like, your solution will be scored by the *characters* that are displayed, not the bytes involved. This is directed at languages with custom encodings.

  - You can assume that I've memorised the entire Unicode library and can say whatever strange characters you use.
- Sorry Rogem, but answers have to be composed of displayable characters. Unprintables are fine, I just have to be able to read the characters out loud.
- Whatever you do, do not use [`ﯹ`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBoybOoMLIAAg09XITKzS09ErzMvMSc1P1kjMSi4o1YVzr//8B) in your program.

Comment: `ARABIC LIGATURE UIGHUR KIRGHIZ YEH WITH HAMZA ABOVE WITH ALEF MAKSURA ISOLATED FORM` this will be the full name of my child

Comment: This program scores 6 in word mode: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/985sbhEwSc1L70kQyG4ICezRMEzr6C0RMEZqCIxuSS1SMHYiDhVXP91ywA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: The reference program is buggy. Consider [this test] (https://tio.run/##dY5PC4JAEMXvfYphYcNsWcrSi@Ahrx3rlB223FTSXdk/oUR9daP1YoceDMPj92Z4LVd1NAya9YDSkikAOIpKsIbDVHsuClNCKq0wcJAGxTN3AqiD7eqNsu4UrIPojOhVNhe6YwXVUhnPp3feL5KEzp@tqoS5AcId4CDUgDc54NBNJhABqXLPpQl8F7VjDQLLqXX/CX2w2vLfoCP@SOJ/4EW1bYbhAw) where `\x[2126]` is counted as `\x[3a9]`.

Answer (score 13):

## Java 8, score <s>[846](https://tio.run/##dU9NC4JAEL33K4ZFwzUb@r4EHuoaneoWxGabSrrKfkQS9ddN14sdGpgHM@@9GV7JZbaqa8UqINuESQA4ilSwnEO/dlzEOoFtYYSGQ6HJemAtQJ6wmHxUZmSJUZFfcMNiVIXUno93XtEwxOGrlKnQNyCuAne2bGB@BXdp@yRIAK2yQzTd8wBG/dGeDvDBMsN/hZbxO2b9j3ijMnldO@PQwZyV3nk6DtuwLNJcYsz1vjE0W4qZzelR2jo8@gU)</s> <s>[838](https://tio.run/##dU@7DoJAEOz9is0FDIe4Mb4aEgppjZV2NqeeYISD3MNojMbaT/UnEI4GCzfZSXZnZjdTcpnNq0qxG5A4ZRIANuIkWM6hW0suEp1CXBihYV1oEvasBcgVpqOnyowscV/kO1ywBFUhtefjmd9oFGH/XsqT0EcgrgJ3PKthcgB3ZnsrSACNskU07fMABt3Rng7wwjLDf4WW8Vsm/Ec8UJm8qpxh5GDOSu/zeg@jJi3bay4x4XpVO5o1xcwm9ShtPB79Ag)</s> <s>[822](https://tio.run/##dU@7DoJAEOz9is0FDIe4MSo2JBTSGivtbE49gQgHuYfRGG39OD8K4Wi0cJOdZHdmdjM1l8WiaRS7AUkyJgFgK3LBSg7fteIi1RkklREaNpUm0cBagFxhPnmqwsgaD1W5xyVLUVVSez6e@Y3GMQ7vtcyFPgFxFbjTsIXZEdzQ9k6QADplj2j65wGMvkd7OsALKwz/FVrG75noH/FAZcqmccaxgyWrvfdrHHdh2UFziSnX69bQbikWNqdHaefw6Ac)</s> [816](https://tio.run/##dU87CsJAEO09xbAQycZkEH@NkEJbsdLOZtU1EZNN2I8YRFtbb@JBvIQ3icmmiYUD82DmvTfDy7lMJmWpWAFkHjMJAGtxFCzl0K4FF5GOYZ4ZoWGVaTLtWAuQC4z6d5UYmeMuS7c4YxGqTGrXwxMvaBhi95rLo9AHII4CZzCuYLgHZ2x7I4gPtbJBNM1zH3rt0Z728cwSw3@FlvEaZvqPuKEyaVl@Xs8grABTlrvvRxDWgdlOc4kR18vKVG0pJjarS2ntcukX)

```java
ௐ->ௐ.map(ˇ->Character.getName(ˇ).length()).sum()
```

-8 score thanks to *@tsh* replacing the `_1` with `ꀊ`.
-22 score thanks to *@ASCII-only* replacing the `ꀊ` with `ˇ` and `$` with `ௐ`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nVLLetJAFN73KY6xaiLk1HpvoVFsq9ILqGi9EKzDMCWBZBIzMyhW2Lr1Tbr2GXwJ38BHwEOgi3jZuJlvzj///P@5DdiIuYPecMYjphQcslCergCEUovshHEBjXmYA8DtAbHR6DBCpTPBYqxL3cpvoJwKEScrdCjNdMihARK2YPbj7Kvr0YExS@3vX1xvO2AZ46SPfaEbLBaEOhgJ2deB7TioTGw7s8pcKTXdiJSWgqMk7EFMGdrkGcp@uwPMWaSnhdK29X9WVp75uUatGK4Vw6aklpg0kcBAh7FAxCJBRSZL0chQkpvyPORJ3J37oGLjInUv2aciihhc8K2Lq5cuX7Gdq6Wyi2vX1q/fuHnr9p27G5uV6pZ3737twfbO7sNHj@t7@weHjeaTp89az18cvXz1@k3b9ztvj9@xLu@Jk34QDoZRLJP0faa0GX34OP50@nkyLdrtJNRg4fJA8CGME5OB7yug6nQggBZC5zzgTAmo/NaoKhUEvlVdPfamU9w9qh341vmtyCy3sdwpQusbxfjn2bciYP2xTvn088fF9GnjFrNvjZUWMSZGY0oPOpK2VZep0ZsAVkktZf/Gahqd06ySRG4r5LQuivbi31@WWU1mvwA)

**Explanation:**

The `ௐ` and `ˇ` are used instead of the `s` and `c` I would normally use, because lowercase letters are all 20 (i.e. `LATIN SMALL LETTER S`), but `ௐ` (`TAMIL OM`) is 8 and `ˇ` (`CARON`) is 5.

```java
ௐ->                         // Method with IntStream parameter and integer return-type
  ௐ.map(ˇ->                 //  Map each character to:
      Character.getName(ˇ)  //   Get the name of the character
               .length())   //   Get the length of that name
   .sum()                   //  And after the map: sum all lengths together,
                            //  and return it as result
```

Comment: I like how this Java stuff beats the 05AB1E answer both in terms of bytes and it terms of score...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ikr. Builtins ftw I guess. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It does save a *couple* bytes that you don't have to `push compressed integer 87235805968599116032550323044578484972930006625267106917841` :P

Comment: Use `ꀊ` instead of `_1` would save some points.

Comment: @tsh Thanks! Completely forgot other 'weird' characters besides regular letters and `_$` are possible as well for variables.

Comment: Remember _ is shorter >_> also the ohm sign Peter Taylor used if that's valid in Java

Comment: @ASCII-only Just `_` isn't allowed in Java, why do you think I had `_1` in the first place.. But your tip on Peter Taylor's answer regarding `ˇ` (`CARON`) does work, so thanks! If you know another one shorter than `11` to replace the `$`, let me know. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Peter Taylor's `Ω` (`OHM SIGN`) is 8 characters long. Also haha I wasn't aware it was not valid, just assumed since it's valid in C# and Peter used `_1` too ([program to find short variable names](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBoybOoMLIAAg09dKLUgs0qlXi9UrzMguK8gvq6vR99Guh4log0bzE3FS95IzEomIFGwVLTb3cRJBEckaR5v//AA), the box character can't  be used)

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks. I've decided to use the `ௐ` (`TAMIL OM`) since it's also 8 bytes.

Answer (score 11):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), score [337](https://tio.run/##dY1PC4JAEMXvfYphQSmVISq7CB7y2rFO1WGrTSXdlf0TSeRX32olsEMD82D4vfemYbJaWqtoCyQrqASALS85rRkMZ814rgvIhOEaNkKTZOQiQO6wmHaqMrLBk6iPuKI5KiH1OMAraydpiv6jkSXXFyCeAm8Wv2V@Bi92u@ckgo@zVzT98wjC4emqI7zRyrBfoyNBT5J/4InK1NaGwRcq9HfdAYU8qxc)

```perl6
+*.uninames.&[~].ords
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFrV4JAEP3c/orJSEBpFZXSEMre7/dbzRCXpGDXWKjowV839JT1ofkw596Ze87MnRmQwJsf@jFkHTCG@RyOqEstn3CcbSZtzIIeH@qIWzFkuM0CsggZBRxJ/FcpyjpyWACS51LCZXhHU34BJJxbkqHF8yAapjgGUquXl6Ggp/0YJIErIFAZDBCKKVLT8migIyUClxUQQVQgEaiOPocNGIdhQqmEChOygA6pTSAaMAoWhK5PMMbwG6mkXKwg7kXBYLK3aWKb@V3MIx@P5qUirVxEO2zXpfcjppYqaDoDM8JsVpTkXF6Zw4WiWipXtPmFam1Rrxvm0nJjZXVtfWNza3tnd2//4PDo@OT07Pzi8ur6ptlq33burK7dI85933149HzKBk8BD6Pnl9f47f3jM/mzIKhaTUVrLOp6ZM7uE/sRYhYF6b0gdRX2CXgWDyEkabItTkCXv81rGqqPP1QXOmaS4PWLxl7mB0z8V6tIaWKlPWZaFam1n5Za@wI)

Comment: That `.&[~]` instead of `.join` is a neat trick. I can never remember what reduction operators can be applied through that method

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a1 `-x`, Score <s>926</s> <s>908</s> <s>875</s> <s>865</s> <s>829</s> <s>791</s> [789](https://tio.run/##dY3NasJAFIUh1Fn0CUpXlykRq@FOEjOxIAjVbZe6E@o0nUZpMgnzUxSxj9SH8MXSNtnYRS/cA5fvnHNrqYu0aYw4AF1shQaAldopUUq4nCepcruFReWUhWVl6fS6jQDdQxJ@msLpGrOqfMG5yNFU2g6G@C4P97MZ9o@13in7BtQ34Mf8R8av4PN214oG8OvsFF33PIDR5dlWB/ghCif/Glsy7Mj0P3BC48qmOX9l@aYX3qTRxPOSmLGQYMJ7xAvJFRLCEAlj6JGY8Si6nYwf@CYb8Qj0@vG5jtMTgLqDbw)

Takes input as an array of characters.

```
®cg`061742//0.450./..//.2/5117385`c+51 r\A_p26}  n#
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a1&code=rmNnYAUwGDYxNwICNDIvLzAGLjQ1BQYCMAYELgYGLy4uBi8vLgIGMi81MTEaNzM4NWBjKzUxIHJcQV9wMjZ9ICBuIyA=&input=WyJPIiwibiIsImMiLCJlIiwiICIsInUiLCJwIiwibyIsIm4iLCIgIiwiYSIsIiAiLCJ0IiwiaSIsIm0iLCJlIiwiLiIsIi4iLCIuIl0KLXg=) or [run all test cases on TIO](https://tio.run/##RZDtUtpAFIZnGM0PrsDx12n8oCpsCBLwA7FRqRatICq2RYQlrCRKdkN2t4KtXFIvojdGz9Rx/LGzz57z7vl4H2ikZqPZ3z/eoDufXSjYxUQin7OsrEHyzryRyBpzxDAsQgzLIgkjZzm2vVjc3HK63oZjQ2yuuGYnyhVeAPgSzJrj2blQbAfceu3yqlGrn1QgkCDCQCnWh/tYhKB8BjIYKx8Ukwo8KhlQCVWcBB@cCwU@5f0hg55AkQz4ABkj0Be6hzjS2EJCwF9L0ZAhR1qBVDGKk61kyk0lUxaeGvcY6EhwoKCCkBFCMCqHOo6I5gHHv7JcJp4Ie0TqkEg6wXxVnGIdhA8mLC2vrH5cW99IZ4iVtXObeadQ3Nre2S3tlfc/uQeHR5XPxydfqqdnX89r9YvG5dV18@bb9x@t2/Zdp0t7Xp/dD/zg4XEYchGNYqn0z6fx5PnX75cpNjj6v1HG85n3CBOhY7hFt14XG1J0592i3TXUl3BAMEvLnfJ0SipN98x8A0ymWyTdxtveTiXbmbAB/wA)

(`APOSTROPHE` is omitted from the 6th test case on TIO as Japt can't handle both single and double quotes in the same input string)

---

### Explanation

```
®cg`...`c+51 r\A_p26}  n#      :Implicit input of character array
®                              :Map
 c                             :  Character code
  g                            :  Index into (0-based, with wrapping)
   `...`                       :    The string described below
        c+51                   :    Increment the codepoint of each by 51 (="8cKidj55gebbc9agh895c97a99baa9bba59ebhddMjfkh")
                               :    (Space closes the above method)
             r                 :    Replace
              \A               :      RegEx /[A-Z]/g
                _              :      Pass each match through a function
                 p26           :        Repeat 26 times
                    }          :      End function
                               :    (Space closes the replace method)
                               :  (Space closes the indexing method)
                       n       :  Convert to integer
                        #      :    From base 32 (note the trailing space)
                               :Implicitly reduce by addition and output
```

---

### Building The String

(Scores include the steps and extra characters needed to reverse each modification)

1. The array gave a baseline score of [2161](https://tio.run/##rU49T8MwEN35FadIQVBOVs6pm0aVOtCVESZgMGDaisSJ/IGoEPz1EF8YysBW@/nk9975@XrjmsUweH2AbLPTDgDu7N7q1sDxujF2G3aw6aINcNuFbHXGTyD7gHnx7ZvoevHctU/iWm@F71y4mIk3c7hcr8X5Z@/2NrxClnvIpRpL@QK54vNgM4TUOVURp88Rro4pR6N41000fxvZmU3O6j/jS/jYDsP9EkmiLE4JGjNLpBrVuGmBNEcihsQaqWCtwiWmDtaqpNbJJPaL3yszlcgUUXFwiVKeEuOkpHjw6vEH).
2. Converting each to a single character in a base `>=23` and joining to a string scored [1832](https://tio.run/##dY1Pj4IwEMXvfopJDcZV0hjd7tKQeFive9SblykUikAh/bPRmPWro8JFD7xkXjL5vXnTSlN9dZ3FC5CdQgMAB11orCW86lfq3CnYNV472DeOxJP@BMgZPlc3W3nT0qSpBf3BnNrGuPmClvLysd3S2bU1hXYZkMBCsGYP26QQsH6OmoTwTA5O/fA8hOXr2leH9A8rL9@DPVkMJB4D/9T6uutIlJSjKtITY7kUIuGYq4izhH8j5wKRC4GMS6HStB7VKSsVAT2FOw).
3. Replacing both runs of `m` and `k` with a single, uppercase character scored [963](https://tio.run/##dY1PS8NAEMXvforHSsTWsEh12y6FQtujetNbocwm22zaZBP2j1ikfvWoyaUeHJgHw@@9N6121bTrPJ3ANoYcgDdbWqo1LudZ2yIYbJpoA16bwBZXfQTsA4/3X76KruVZUyu@poL7xoXbMT/q02i55DefrStt2IMlHslE/MhDjkT0u7Usxa9zUB6H5ynuLs@@OuXvVEX919iT8UAW/4Ez97HuOjbPnsr8IEShlcokFWYuRSZnJKUikkqRkFqZPH857I@Gue1q106mZ8Be4xs).
4. There were still too many expensive letters so next I tried to get rid of them by reducing the codepoints of all characters. `5` was the character with the lowest codepoint (`53`) so I started with 52, which scored [756](https://tio.run/##dY1LS8NAFIUJdjb@AXF3GIlom7lJ83JRKGi3Lu2uIGMd22IyCfMQi9S/HjXZ1EUv3AOX75xzW2Wqsuus3IMvttIAWOqdlrXC8TwqvXFbLBqvHZ4ax2fnfQT8E3nybStvWlo39Qs9yA3ZxribMb2r/e18Ttdfrdlp9wYeWoRp8SvZK8Ki35XmEf6cg5IfnkeYHJ99dUQfsvLqv7En44HMToEDWV93HR/FF0VSBkE2JYqZyPIRC2J2JhgjIRiRCNiU8iS5LNO7nK8nRQqzun9u0/IA6Cv8AA)
5. After trying all numbers that would leave *no* letters in the string, `51` gave the best score of [738](https://tio.run/##dY1PS8NAEMUh2D34CcTTYyWibZhN0mwqFAraq0e9FWSta1tMNmH/iEXqV4@aXOrBgXkw/N5702pblV3n1B58uVUWwKPZGVVrHM@9Nhu/xbIJxuOh8Xx@2kfAP1CkX64KtqV1Uz/TndqQa6y/GtOb3l8vFnT52dqd8a/gsUOcyx@ZviCW/a4MT/DrHJTC8DzB5PjsqxN6V1XQf409GQ9k/h84kAt11/FRelZmsygqciFSRoUcsShlJ8SYIGJCUMRyIbPsfDa9kXw9kRns6vapzcsDYC7wDQ)
6. Finally, replacing the quotation marks with slightly cheaper backticks gave a score of [734](https://tio.run/##dY1BS8NAEIUh2D34C8TTYyWibZhN0mwqFAraq0e9Fexa17aYbMLuRixS/3rU5NIeOjAPhu@9N7W2Rd62Tu3A5xtlATybrVGlxuE8arP2G8yrxng8VZ5Pz7sI@Bey@McVja1pVZWv9KDW5Crrb4b0oXe3sxldf9d2a/w7eOgQpvJPxm8IZbcLwyP8O3ulpn8eYXR4dtURfaqi0cfGjgx7Mj0F9uSasm2Xg/giTyZBkKVCxIwyOWBBzM6IMUHEhKCApUImyeVkfCeXq5FMYBf3L3Wa7wFzhV8). Backticks in Japt are usually used to enclose and decompress a compressed string but, luckily, none of the characters in this string are contained in Shoco's library

The final string, so, contains the characters at the following codepoints:

```
[5,48,24,54,49,55,2,2,52,50,47,47,48,6,46,52,53,5,6,2,48,6,4,46,6,6,47,46,46,6,47,47,46,2,6,50,47,53,49,49,26,55,51,56,53]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score [963](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJByTkjsUhBQSE0LzMvMTdVARn4pOall2QoOOeX5pUohOSXKFlzgbUoKFUomBjUFeeUFhXoJefnJuk5JabrFecXlWho6WWnVmra2empVRcUZeaVpCkoqRYrqBqZAgnjFAVVUzCOyVPSUQCphJB6pRDLdRS0kblgo3X0yhJzSlNRFYJltCAy1rgkavWKS3P//z/cV/aoYZHbuS2HFzxqmGVjYG95aG/uucUOh6cf2@b8qKmxLFn3Ucui0nNT4s9tVQeqNDK8sOncVhfjRw07M42Mzm181NR0YUdt7ek5lYfbjY10D6/QBgA)

```
Îv•Fδà‚<0?9½mΣ@×ƶC₁vc-™uΔ_ε'•21вεD3‹i22α₂и}}˜yÇ32-è+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AbsARP9vc2FiaWX//8OOduKAokbOtMOg4oCaPDA/OcK9bc6jQMOXxrZD4oKBdmMt4oSidc6UX861J@KAojIx0LLOtUQz4oC5aTIyzrHigoLQuH19y5x5w4czMi3DqCv//yAhIiMkJSYnKCkqKywtLi8wMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ojs8PT4/QEFCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaW1xdXl9gYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXp7fH1@) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkr1B5f@yRw2L3M5tObzgUcMsGwN7y0N7c88tdjg8/dg250dNjWXJuo9aFpWemxJ/bqs6UKWR4YVN57a6GD9q2JlpZFSp@6ip6cKO2trTcyoPtxsb6R5eof2/Vue/I5c@l39ecqpCaUF@nkKiQklmbqqenh5XcU5pUYFeaV5mXmJuarGdnV5yfm6SXnFprl5xYiWXV753Zl46l6KSgrKKqpq6hqaWto6unr6BoZGxiamZuYWllbWNrZ29g6OTs4urm7uHp5e3j6@ff0BgUHBIaFh4RGRUdExsXHxCYlJySmpaekZmVnZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZVV1TW0dl0t@aVJOqm5yRmpytkJlfmmRQkyxAtCZJRmpCjmJxSUKJalAIjmxOFXBWpPLBugyBSUblXi7ujo91zBHHyUYg0snWk8nlsvQEgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Î               # Push 0 and the input-string
 v              # Loop `y` over the characters of this input-string:
  •Fδà‚<0?9½mΣ@×ƶC₁vc-™uΔ_ε'•
               '#  Push compressed integer 87235805968599116032550323044578484972930006625267106917841
   21в          #  Converted to Base-21 as list: [5,16,14,11,11,12,9,10,16,17,8,9,5,12,9,7,10,9,9,11,10,10,9,11,11,10,5,9,14,11,17,13,13,0,19,15,20,17,8,12,2,18,13,19,5]
    ε           #  Map over this list:
     D3‹i       #   If the value is smaller than 3:
         22α    #    Take the absolute difference of this value with 22
            ₂и  #    Repeat it 26 times as list
    }}          #  Close the if-statement and map
      ˜         #  Flatten the list
       yÇ       #  Get the unicode value of the current character
         32-    #  Subtract 32
            è   #  Index it into the list of integers
             +  #  And add it to the sum
                # (and output the sum implicitly as result after the loop)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•Fδà‚<0?9½mΣ@×ƶC₁vc-™uΔ_ε'•21в` is `[5,16,14,11,11,12,9,10,16,17,8,9,5,12,9,7,10,9,9,11,10,10,9,11,11,10,5,9,14,11,17,13,13,0,19,15,20,17,8,12,2,18,13,19,5]`.

Answer (score 4):

## R; Score: <strike>3330</strike> <strike>1586</strike> 1443

Also challenging in R due to lack of built-ins.

Well the code is now mostly @Giuseppe's but that's alright. I was able to make a small edit to golf further by replacing the * with the ~, and the s with the dot.

Thanks to @Nick Kennedy for getting this down to 1443 by using <strike>arcane magic</strike> "a UTF8 encoded version of the number sequence"

```
function(.)sum((c(+",752230178/0,30.1002110221,052844",61~26,+":6;8/3",59~26,+"94:,")-39)[+.-31]);`+`=utf8ToInt;`~`=rep
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##xc09DoIwFADgu3ShTR/w3usPBeQA7m7GpAmxCYPFIKxcvQ4ewvGbvq2kS13Sked9WbNs1Od4STlLLaBzzAapCy2CwYYQmQiZCdBxsFaAp5M9aDH4MbRGgOt/7u0AQtWmV3fd1IYeaow6Tseewm295n2MZ5y257skWf2prlT5Ag)

Comment: [1769 points](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYs7g0VyNZw1TH0EzH0ETH0BCMjHQsdQwNwGLmOhZAjilEzBwkagmSNATLG0CZYJ4piAMxAqjOGISMjLSMgGYAxU11jAwghgENMjIAC1uAVQEN14wuLUmzCMn3zCsBukjX2DBW0zpBK8G2KLXgf5qGEv1cS02ExdfURHhDT0mTi67hRmksK2n@BwA) -- makes a minimal attempt to compress the values...

Comment: also, `utf8ToInt` is a super helpful command for golfing :-) I haven't been on PPCG for a month or so, so it's nice to see new people golfing in R!

Comment: Ah, I had a way to compress it, but was not aware of utf8ToInt. I'll have to work on this later tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: [1617](https://tio.run/##zVJBCsIwELz7Cukp0QjZtGka1Ad49yaCUCx4sIq276@zG72oeBKRXcjsZDPMJrkMzXgxG5q@rbvDqVVXfe2Pyk9rZQ2RiaZEBFMYzyU5kwNbYRy4AlFi9bIyskB8Cq0VgsLEoSgMQc8ngQAkbM4NkNObvmuq9WnVdjAwy2mr57vJbnnZn4dGZU/magWdpEl3U1HkwQUoRuMTF5iNvEmyb@9QKs9FkgjsBOncN5MiD@xsMgVDgF9MqsQ1hn1ze5ke/fTe5DVf5xX6k8/HK7/1@z@fMNPDDQ) -- I'm just making random edits instead of doing my actual work :-(

Comment: Well I appreciate it. What does the footer do over at TIO?

Comment: It's just more lines of code under the program/snippet that doesn't affect bytecount - useful to do some tests in

Comment: Also see the C# solution, I'm sure you can do something similar, just gotta do `asc` first, the lookup table logic should be mostly the same?

Comment: if packages are allowed `function(.)sum(nchar(u_char_name(as.u_char(utf8ToInt(.)))));library(Unicode)` is 1388.

Comment: Down to 1443: https://tio.run/##xc09DoIwFADgu3ShTR/w3usPBeQA7m7GpAmxCYPFIKxcvQ4ewvGbvq2kS13Sked9WbNs1Od4STlLLaBzzAapCy2CwYYQmQiZCdBxsFaAp5M9aDH4MbRGgOt/7u0AQtWmV3fd1IYeaow6Tseewm295n2MZ5y257skWf2prlT5Ag Using a UTF8 encoded version of the number sequence.

Answer (score 4):

### C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) (score <strike>1627 1116 1096 1037 1019</strike> 902)

```
Ω=>Ω.Sum(ˇ=>(31&-ˇ)>5&ˇ>62?22-ˇ/91*2:"♁♌♊♇♇♈♅♆♌♍♄♅♁♈♅♃♆♅♅♇♆♆♅♇♇♆♁♅♊♇♍♉♉♏♋♐♍♄♈♎♉♏♁"[ˇ-6-ˇ/33*26]-9788)
```

This uses no built-in database: just some special-casing for letters and a lookup table.

[Online test suite](https://tio.run/##rVLtVtNAEP2/T7GsiAlN0yYhbUPbIAqoUEVBQW0rpumWrrRJzUcBazinR6B@69@8gC/Tt8iL1M2mRfzPnjnJ3Luzd2dmx3TTpksmG75lllzPIdahQCxPb5Un0fmfsk4/4q7f5cajss4p0kJ6POJ1dWE80nPyiixTmNGkRXkZReEwCr9H4dcoHDH7HIUXUXjJyB9ReM7gcMZ/YlsXzEbMv5z5CRwymKjR41@Y/YrCb1H4eyZIpX7O@CGqjkfpXJyQoizKuXpayxcK/KQIaDnVOsQnPWx6uAnL0MLHkJEDVZBygrQkSBIzWdAEKcu4vFCgQE24fMxq8abE9rNTlyE1BokEjVNik@WbNInqq4KcTZKiCVH3Bk0qsKxpsUERgJbtQI42BxLaqGyR/kpXrRMr2Dr02pRMpXg4AJCuvuFAu@Fip89a2@IQginImW3D4TlCXUXm@SILJS3IzaSqpA7nylcnZ2rx2neIhyvEwtw8Wt/Z2d6BA5JS5AAO/lelxDU1imZiAZpeGIAA/FNDG8QibpumabaxeUQHnQ5Bk/RJ0zc6sIM9DztufDTuATbMNhfXZtCgeGDosAC0igSYyUBZBiiTuHmAti0TQ79nWzTWI10simKyp2SXAHI7vtMTfYtYRhe7ui6adrchun5XdI3TJE5VsgBt2ls0o4SQZHpwrobgrfnbC3c4fjElpMVMVpKVJTWXL2jLxVJZX7m7eu/@2vrGg4ePNrcqj59sP322s/v8xd7@y1evq7Va/c3BW6NhNnHrsE3eHXW6lt1777ie3z8@Of0w@BicTe9SNQmgNdtvdHCaNQae2r4DazUX0pK8NoYdw/Wgh@nHNFwMi/y0dFUFqESrgDVUmj/Qz87E9b3VSg3NvGkXCgWAhKoo1KfVUihp08s1EPDg@oMPDEFTAwjLOoSDFmfw8WNO/gI).

It can't score itself, because most of the characters are not in range, including the variables `CARON` and `OHM SIGN` and the zodiac symbols used to encode the lookup table.

Thanks to [ASCII-only](/users/39244) for many suggestions.

Comment: What scoring program did you use

Comment: tio.run/##NZDrdpNAFIX/z1OMY0wgwhCg0NAEanpT22jVaquGiAQnYbgMhIHWGJO36gv0xSJrBf@cdS57r72@E3A54HR3UbFgyMuCsoVEWenM7d3To@08PeKbKhU82xG2suDJdgd2xLauikPNbLc9R9eONU32FFPtakeI5CyOExrly5CShC4iSuMoonEcEcriZZryrFyGSZFygiZebdP1rmZOZcsUdwMwzwriB6Fw7xfQh5RBRh4m0zVAIyRBRYGaBpCybw8BumYBgVWesVpb0pRgjPc3vXcAEE@qIscVo8xPCXccHGTpDPMqxdxf7XWG3gPoMruqifcLVauNz1wEn7detDuC2H0pyVjpqZp@YJiHfetoMLSd41ejk9Oz84vXb95eXo3fvb/@8PHTzecvt3dfv32fuO70h/fTnwW/yHwR0ihOUpbly4KX1f3D79Wf9d/NtskyLBWgs6yaJUQOQhLEcJVVBXRdDmukMiQw8XkJS1KXwOcEDsQG3TAAGtYU0EXDludst/j8djR20f@u@UK/D5A0wdK0oa1H1WrCLbARwV1BSzKmjAgttPYly9hAaDsQrueCL26QONj9Aw

Comment: This should be 1590 whereas yours seems to score 1735 on the reference implementation

Comment: tio.run/##NZDrdpNAFIX/z1OMY0wgwsDMAIEkUNOb2karVls1RCQ4abBhiAy0xpi8VV@gLxZZK/HPWeey99rrO4nUE5luTyuR9GVZpOJGS0UZTP3t44MfPD7gyypTIj9QNroS6X4LttQmI2qfOs1mFDB6QKkeGQ5p0y7SOjalzCQd1zA1ZmJimpQQk1KimTZ1Lavr9FyDeVZXQ6OotjHWps5YZ5667YFpXvA4mSl3cQFjmAoo@P1ovAJogDRoGJBSgIxd2wHoQiQcVotc1NoyzTjGeHdjpgWQnFfFAlciFXHGZRDgJM8mWFYZlvFyp7OZCdBZfl4T7xaE1sYnIYJPG8@aLUVtP9d0bJiEMst2Oq7X7fX94ODF4PDo@OT05avXZ@fDN28v3r3/cPnx09X15y9fR2E4/hZ9jyfJDz69maU/b@eZyBe/CllWd/e/l39Wf9ebfZbtEYCO82oy53oy48ktXOZVAcNQwhqpnHE4j2UJS16XJJYc9tQ9um0D1K8pYIj6jSjYbPDJ1WAYov/d/guuC5A2wtp4T1uPxNuHe2CtgusiLfkwFVxpoFWsefYaQj@AcDVVYnWN1N72Hw

Comment: Should score 1120?

Comment: @ASCII-only, I used the Python answer below; the Java answer also gives 1627. The problem seems to be that the reference solution is buggy: Ω is U+2126, [OHM SIGN](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf), not GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA.

Comment: What's the micro one then? (Also replaced micro sign with ohm sign, 1116 now)

Comment: Aargh, I missed a subtraction of 32 to fix the index in my program to find the best offset for the lookup table. `µ` is MICRO SIGN.

Comment: https://tio.run/##NZDbdpNAGIXv5ynGMUaIMDDDIRAONT2pbbRqtVVDRIKTBhuGyEBrjMmVz@KD@SKRtYI3e/2nvfb6/lSoqch2pzVPfVGVGb9RMl6Fs2D39/efIGwEX9a5FAehtFXjrkFkn9rdbhza5IBSNdZcu0cHSOlblBo66Tuarhg6JrpOCdEpJYpuUcc0B7bnaIZrDhQ0jlW7MRpGj9oT1XDlnQdmRcmSdC7dJSVMYMYhZ/fjyRqgIVKgpkFKAdL2ZR@gC54yWC8L3txWWc4wxvudoZsAiUVdLnHNM57kTIQhTot8ikWdY5Gs9neWoQN0Vpw3uPsBoY3xQYTgw86j7mNJ7j1RVKzphBqmZfcdd@D5QXjwdHh4dHxy@uz5i7Pz0ctXF6/fvL189/7q@sPHT@MomnyOvyTT9Cub3cyzb7eLnBfL76Wo6rv7H6uf61@bbZtluQSg46KeLpiazll6C1dFXcIoErBBquYMLhJRwYo1kiaCQU9u0S0LIL@hgBHyO3G43eKTq@EoQv@r9guOA5AyxsqkpW1a4rbhLtjI4LrMKjbKOJM6aJ0orrWBMAghXM@kRN4g2dv9Aw

Comment: Score 1055 I think?

Comment: @ASCII-only, I've made further savings by using `&` instead of `&&` and by reworking the comparison against `26` into a comparison against `5`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89983/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-peter-taylor).

Comment: Score 5 name: ˇ, no other names shorter than 8 that C# accepts, also not verified with Java program

Comment: Why do you use `Ω`?.. It's name is `GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA`, which is even longer than just a letter.. The challenge description has a Perl 6 program to get your score.

Comment: @Kevin, as per my earlier comment the reference implementation is buggy. I think it's applying normalisation to turn the source character OHM SIGN into GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah ok. I also just noticed the same thing with the `KELVIN SIGN` which it changes to `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K`.. Nice score for a overall pretty verbose language without builtins for the challenge nor compression btw, +1 from me!

Comment: I'm honestly surprised how close this comes to the builtin-based Java answer (and even the Perl answer). Granted, letters are very, _very_ expensive using this scoring method which explains the closeness. Also @PeterTaylor `>64` -> `>62` for -1 score should work?

Comment: @ASCII-only, now beating Python...

Comment: Haha, of course there's a better offset. I thought about it but doubted there would be a contiguous block of characters with names that short, I guess I just forgot you don't need a very wide range since the range of values being encoded is pretty small

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), Score of 993

```python
lambda _:len(''.join(map(__import__('unicodedata').name,_)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5ZU8IwGHzPr/hEtKmWAOLFVUXBA1A88QCMoQQItEltUxUP/jpWZ9yHnd2d2dn1Z3qsZG4xLHcXLvP6Awa04HKJDYNMlJDYYz6mVHi@CjSl2IikcNSAD5hmhkkk87hFTdNcDFUAFISEgMkRx9mMWUAQQ0A5Tv1IY/PP@4GQGgsLjLJtWDDEIi5XUBq1pMMh8pUEBlp4nBCCQjcKfBJP/u6Etk0c5fVJGHkkZDNUVw0hR2gpAcvJlVUDm2vrVoqkM9mN3ObW9s5uvlAsle29/crBYbV2dHxyWm80z85bF5dX1ze37bv7h8dOt/dEn1nfGfDhaCwmU9eTyn8JQh29vr3PPj6/vueoqqK@y1POmDtTmKkogG4I8U095uCyUIPmMTks5FA0USl@BolSktrzOam1K83Ev0BWh1g9lM3/AA)

Below 1000 now, any tips still appreciated.

-16 thanks to Kirill L.

Comment: [993](https://tio.run/##NU5ZU8IwGHzPr/hEtKmWAOLFVUXBA1A88QCMoQQItEltUxUP/jpWZ9yHnd2d2dn1Z3qsZG4xLHcXLvP6Awa04HKJDYNMlJDYYz6mVHi@CjSl2IikcNSAD5hmhkkk87hFTdNcDFUAFISEgMkRx9mMWUAQQ0A5Tv1IY/PP@4GQGgsLjLJtWDDEIi5XUBq1pMMh8pUEBlp4nBCCQjcKfBJP/u6Etk0c5fVJGHkkZDNUVw0hR2gpAcvJlVUDm2vrVoqkM9mN3ObW9s5uvlAsle29/crBYbV2dHxyWm80z85bF5dX1ze37bv7h8dOt/dEn1nfGfDhaCwmU9eTyn8JQh29vr3PPj6/vueoqqK@y1POmDtTmKkogG4I8U095uCyUIPmMTks5FA0USl@BolSktrzOam1K83Ev0BWh1g9lM3/AA)

Comment: You can replace `_` by `ˇ` for 987.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, score [723](https://tio.run/##dY/LCsJADEX3fkUYrI8agvjaiC50K7pRcCHI2I612M6UeYhF6q9rbTe6MJAL4dwk3EzoZPJ6GZ4DW164BoCdjCVPBXzXSsjIXmCpnLSwVZZNG9UKsDuM@k@TOJ1RoNITLXhERmnb8ekq8u58Tq1HpmNpz8A8A95gXMowBG9c9UEyhI@zVnL1c4Te91idRrrxxIlfY0X8mkz/gYKMS8uQeFg/NvvCJzwGZdaPzbRvMQ9UKEDpsNnCSGDzOMsRMXgD)

```
s,\N{OX}*.,_charnames'viacode ord$&,ge,$_=y,,,c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LUsIwAADv@YpYKwiGICoqAlUUfACCT0QBaxpiW2mT2jRoRfh0K@OMl5097WzAQq@YJBINO7Nuf57FyKQOCTnxmUxPXULFmEERjvUUshnSzWqMEKJJUgN50OWUQRUIDgmMXJ9hjIH0VBhgxd2/gmFgKnwLS@VjSWLQFC2X22BFg6v6Wiq9nsluoBzObxa2tneKu3v7pYNypWocHtWOT@qN07Pzi2arfdnpXl3f3N7d9x76j0@D4ejZfCEWHbNX23HfJp7PRfAeykhNPz7jr9n3fAHqQlkey1GH0QmMhQrhUMLlZuQw6BEZwYgtQYlksJwBleUZ1Cq6aSwWuNGrtbV/AWiA0QgUSj8iiFzBZZILvF8)

#### Explanation

```
s,        ,                        ,ge  # Replace globally
  \N{OX}*   # zero or more OX characters , loads the
            # _charnames module as side effect,
         .  # any character
           _charnames'viacode ord$&  # with its Unicode character name
                                     # (using old package delimiter).
                                      ,$_=y,,,c  # Set $_ to its length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), [1934](https://tio.run/##dU1tT4JQFP7erzhexcjwzoG0KWUONz@ZtSmrLKQroLCAy@5Li5n9dTL4Yh8623l2znleTh6y5KosOSkATSLCAMDJ4oykIZzWLMx2IoIJlZmAJRXIOqssgD6h3/vmiWQ59mm6wTbZYU6ZUDv4PSwuRiPc3ucszsQWkMJB0c0jGAEoZtWvGdLgV1kjlvVzDS5P1ypawx8kkeFfYcV0asb6jzhgLtOyXMh0vF9Sm/DwZcpoWg33LOBj1FjZBZM3zcHWft60iLGIe@vc0VYPTaPlB@eq3/WSSLqR6ppW4/Hr9q4/vPbW3LHm7afp/E0MJeoaujYwXU033DrUO17cww8)

```
Sum@{ToBase[FromBase[Ords@"!ZByru=#9fBYb$a3Si0^pU,ZP#3$cd'(c-_lhu]h(]5;!W|?M4:<_^sU;N&XFN`t:u"-32,95],23][Ords@_-32]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBLTwIxFIX3/IpSJopJqcrIgqeAysIHkAA@GMtQSmEa55Vpu5io/PWxEcadrryr7z5yzs2hSlHm8WwDGu1sooPu@zTqU8mdQRIF3zBK1rILi/N@muh2qb7pv6wsak/E2SKeofm4ZFtsfVxmFdf3NPHKpNYsPn1cPlw0Wu5CzprDo@fBcKkaGlbsKqrXCKraZC/qmgn5zIacr6VjxTHbksI4EaGacqmujLd0Ngg4BWAK9iDaw2kOo5BxoOMoBBQoEXCMcb6Svk5irEMR0oDLTgezKFhhqQMsaZof3UZ3ItweOiqZEHtcwutIr3xeMbmwN5BGOgGvEhgf5XHgU6mAMg8CZj4EzZNcrmWkAYQty@3sdvjmsXcP4Q8dbpCDEcmb83pOf@T@H8H/ljwsEJJ9AQ)

Simple compression and indexing.

Comment: :P looks like using a smarter lookup (see C# answer) would help with score. Or even just using a charset that doesn't contain letters to compress

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), Score: <s>4007</s> <s>3988</s> <s>3759</s> <s>3551</s> 2551

```cs
ˇ=>ˇ.Sum(_=>new[]{5,16,14,11,11,12,9,10,16,17,8,9,5,12,9,7,10,9,9,11,10,10,9,11,11,10,5,9,14,11,17,13,13,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,19,15,20,17,8,12,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,18,13,19,5}[_-32])
```

I feel crushed by Peter Taylor's solution up above. Thanks to Peter Taylor for pointing out a simple lookup table was better than my previous dictionary solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHhWtMwFP3PU8Q6tdUsNB1lq1sLU0CFKSoK6jpnFjMWWdPZNMCY3V8ejoeat52@AflOknvPSW5OEq7rXMvVgVG8o/NMqnMsVR6Nw9XdbRjd3ZITk9jDMFLiqj9Y@JhuY7qFKa3g4QBTt@KauAWJv@aaJRuUIq10919YZX6ZrEvAukYJz7tPUKjvY89dmwJDEN4jaKtyDZct@sN6wxs4q/bGOM0E4xP7kmWIIanQ@r2sroWtTejHigtkZqkCNZeJIIQAq6cmmxGjpGKJ0FFEeJqMiDYJ0WwO@mF6BB8CwYPYQg9rjx4/sZ2nz3CdbLrUa2z5281W8LzdCaOd3e6Ll3v7B69evzk86r19d/z@w8eTT59Pz758/daP48H34Q824j/F@Hwif11ME5XOfmc6N5dX1/ObxZ9iCWfspWY0FXU@EfwCzVOToTjWCBznE4GmTOcoFzBwpgVqO7ChAyZRbHVqw2i5JPun3V5s/Y9Axn2CBzDTwCqcjbNM5qInlbBr1oLhwC0QtDAqx8XYZk5hOe3VXw)

Comment: This is considerably worse than a direct lookup table: `_1=>_1.Select(_2=>new int[]{5,16,14,11,11,12,9,10,16,17,8,9,5,12,9,7,10,9,9,11,10,10,9,11,11,10,5,9,14,11,17,13,13,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,19,15,20,17,8,12,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,18,13,19,5}[_2-32]).Sum()` scores 2786.